# how to return data from php to ajax success call

Tags: php, ajax

nali.php

```
$tagId = mysqli_insert_id($link);
  echo $tagId; 

at ajax success call

$.ajax({
        url: "nail.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {Tag:tag},
        success: function(data) {
            $enter_tag_id = data.tagId;
           alert(data);
        }
    });
```

i get the correct echo at php page . but not get any value at ajax success.i want to save tagId to a variable at ajax success

Comment: success: function(data) {
            $enter_tag_id = data;
           alert(data);
        }

Answer (score 0):

Update your ajax code:
`success: function(data) {
            //$enter_tag_id = data;
           alert(data);
        }`